# How to put an application on an iPhone/iPad device?

Tags: iphone, ios4, ipad

I have an application that I developped using the iPhone/iPad simulator.

I am now at the point I want to test it on a real device.

I just got a license from apple.

Where should I go on the net to find out the information on how to transfer my application to a real device ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow any one of these links :-

1) http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html

2) http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices

EDIT : If you've got the license , go to your Apple ID -> Provisioning Portal -> Certificates -> Download the Certificate.

Save it to the Disk. 
Double Click on it to install.
Open your XCode.
Change the Build from Simulator to Device (Make Sure your device is connected.)
Just Build and Run.

Hope this can help you :-)

Answer (score 3):

Check out this article,

http://mayurbirari.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/ad-hoc-distribution-build-for-iphone/

you can create adhoc build and install this application not only on your device but on multiple devices.

Answer (score 2):

Follow Apple's guide here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/128-Managing_Devices_and_Digital_Identities/devices_and_identities.html

Answer (score 2):

If you log into the [iOS Dev Center](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action) using your new account details, you will find a link on the right-hand side named "iOS Provisioning Portal".

When you reach the portal home page, there is a panel that allows you to launch the Provisioning Assistant wizard.  This will walk you through the process.

This may be worth following for the first time, then evaluate the entries in the various parts of the provisioning portal to see how you can set this up manually in future.

Answer (score 1):

If you've followed all the instructions for setting your development environment up after signing up for the Developer program it's just a case of changing the target from Simulator to Device in XCode and then running it. Your app will be transferred to the device and executed on it.